# Off center flexbox nav item

Tags: html, css

My central nav item in the footer is off-center, and I'm not sure how to center it while still keeping the same amount of space between links.  My fix to center it was to add `margin-right: 45px`, as seen at the very bottom of the css file (it's commented out in the codepen).  The additional margin throws off the even spacing.

How do I keep the nav-container a flexbox, while centering the middle link, with even spacing between all three links?

I'm not even sure what I'm going for would look good.  It might make the entire nav bar look off center since the left and right links aren't the same text length, I'm just frustrated that I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

https://codepen.io/pmc222/full/bxzGyy/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wedding-index.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Mc-Stamm Wedding</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="main-header">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    <a class="main-header__link" href="index.html">The Mc-Stamm Wedding</a>
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  </header>

  <main class="main-container">
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-one"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Walking down beach to the proposal"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-two"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Close to the proposal spot"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-three"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Before kneeling"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-four"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Proposing"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-five"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="She said yes!"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-six"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Hugging"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-seven"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Kissing"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-eight"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Dramatic kiss"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-nine"><img src="http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/146/25102-colorful-high-resolution-background.jpg" alt="Walking back down beach"></div>
    <div class="main-container__image main-container__image-ten"><img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/portocala/portocala1612/portocala161200021/67690040-abstract-geometric-background-circle-generic-backdrop-for-design-square-template-vector.jpg?ver=6" alt="Engaged couple"></div>
    <p class="main-container__paragraph main-container__paragraph-one">Please join us</p>
    <p class="main-container__paragraph main-container__paragraph-two">September 28, 2019</p>
  </main>

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <a class="main-nav__link" href="venue-information.html">Venue Information</a>
      <a class="main-nav__link" href="accommodations.html">Accommodations</a>
      <a class="main-nav__link" href="wedding-party.html">Wedding Party</a>
    </nav>
  </footer>  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Wedding Index CSS */

/* browser reset */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
/* end of browser reset */

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

/* Makes <header> element a flexbox */
.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/* Styles index link */
.main-header__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* Styles and positions icons */
.fas {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 15px;
}

/* Makes <main> element a grid-box */
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(28, auto) / repeat(100, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(42, 136, 212), rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(42, 136, 212));
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Transition: scale() duration for div containing images */
.main-container__image {
  transition: ease .3s; 
}

/* Styles images inside div's */
.main-container__image img {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 245);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Positions div's on grid and controls overlap depth */
.main-container__image-one {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 9 / 13;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-container__image-two {
  grid-area: 6 / 12 / 14 / 24;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-container__image-three {
  grid-area: 11 / 23 / 19 / 35;
  z-index: 3;
}

.main-container__image-four {
  grid-area: 16 / 34 / 24 / 46;
  z-index: 4;
}

.main-container__image-five {
  grid-area: 21 / 45 / 29 / 57;
  z-index: 5;
}

.main-container__image-six {
  grid-area: 16 / 56 / 24 / 68;
  z-index: 4;
}

.main-container__image-seven {
  grid-area: 11 / 67 / 19 / 79;
  z-index: 3;
}

.main-container__image-eight {
  grid-area: 6 / 78 / 14 / 90;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main-container__image-nine {
  grid-area: 1 / 89 / 9 / 101;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main-container__image-ten {
  grid-area: 1 / 43 / 16 / 59;
}
/* End of positioning rules */

/* Makes primary image a circle */
.main-container__image-ten img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Set scale size and depth of hovered image div's */
.main-container__image:hover {
  transform: scale(3.9);
  z-index: 6;
}

/* The following rules position scaled image div's on hover */
.main-container__image-one:hover {
  transform-origin: 0% 3%;
}

.main-container__image-two:hover {
  transform-origin: 30% 25%;
}


.main-container__image-three:hover,
.main-container__image-seven:hover {
  transform-origin: 50% 47%;
}

.main-container__image-four:hover,
.main-container__image-six:hover {
  transform-origin: 50% 69%;
}


.main-container__image-five:hover  {
  transform-origin: 50% 92%;
}

.main-container__image-eight:hover {
  transform-origin: 70% 25%;
}

.main-container__image-nine:hover {
  transform-origin: 100% 3%;
}

.main-container__image-ten:hover {
  transform-origin: 50% 7%;
  transform: scale(2); /* Changed scale for primary image div */
}
/* End of positioning rules for scaled image div's */

/* Changes primary image border shape from circle to same as other image div's on hover */
.main-container__image-ten:hover img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Styles "Please join us" and "September 28, 2019" */
.main-container__paragraph {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: "Great Vibes", cursive;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* Positions "Please join us" on grid */
.main-container__paragraph-one {
  grid-area: 23 / 9 / 27 / 26;
}

/* Positions "September 28, 2019" on grid */
.main-container__paragraph-two {
  grid-area: 23 / 72 / 27 / 97;
}

/* Style and positons <footer> element */
.main-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 30px;
}

/* Makes <nav> container a flexbox and positions flex items */
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Styles link flex items */
.main-nav__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

/* .main-nav__link:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 45px; /* pushed middle link more toward center, but disrupted space-evenly positioning */
} */
```

Comment: Do you need the even spacing only between links or also between links and window ?

Comment: I did not think it would be possible to have even spacing between both links and the edge of the window considering the first and third links have different sizes.  If they have the same space between their outer border and the browser edge, there can't be the same amount of space between the actual links while still keeping the central one centered in the page.  Right?  Twisting my brain around this one has got me a little confused.  I would settle for at least knowing how to center the middle link and then have the same amount of space between it's border and the other links.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it is possible with CSS do get everyting evenly spaced with an item centered, and using JS for that would be a bit 'ugly'.

Comment: While not code related, I ended up changing the order of my links from "Venue Information.....Accommodations.....Wedding Party" to "Venue Information...Wedding Party...Accommodations".  Venue Information and Accommodations are closer to being the same length than Venue Information and Wedding Party, so the middle link (Wedding Party) required less margin to center, thus making the space between the links closer to being even than the way I had it before.  Won't always work out, but it's the best I have right now.

Comment: Please check my answer to see if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center your middle link and have even spacing between your items like this :

```
.main-nav__link:not(:nth-of-type(2)) { flex: 1; }
.main-nav__link:first-child { text-align: right; }
.main-nav__link:nth-of-type(2) { margin: 0 10%; } /* Or any other value */
.main-nav__link:last-child { text-align: left; }
```

And remove on `.main-nav`:

```
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

The `flex: 1;` property tells your items to take the remaining space. Since with this code both your first and last items have this property, they are sharing the remaining space equally thus pushing the middle item on the center.

Note that with this solution the responsive might be a bit broken because of the set `margins` on the middle item. Using a `media-query` might be necessary if you want it to be full responsive.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  The central link is technically not centered because of the letter-spacing applied also comes after the last letter, which apparently is a bug in chome and firefox.  It doesn't really matter visually because it's such a minute amount of spacing that it's hard to tell without inspecting the page, but logically it hurts my brain.  Regardless, your code did exactly what I wanted it to.  Thanks!

Comment: One question regarding this solution.  I had a 2px border-bottom show up when hovering over the links.  With the solution the left and right links have borders that extend to the edge of each page.  Is there a way to only underline the text, without using text-decoration?

Comment: @pmc222 I am glad I could help ! Yes, you can wrap your text inside a `span` tag and then put the hover effect on `.main-nav__link span:hover`

Comment: Ah ha!  Thanks! That helps.